# Register user with empty password

Tags: services

I create a cordova app, and trying to register new user from my app using drupa 7, drupal 7 service 3 and angularjs 1.

I send post request with below data and user created successfully.

```
    $http({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $rootScope.globals.auth.token
        },
        method: "POST",
        url: registerUrl,
        data: {
            name: data.name,
            pass: data.password,
            mail: data.email,
            "field_ac_mobile_number": {"und": [{"value": data.mobile}]}
        }
    }).success(function(userData) {
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

But my problem is- **after create user, password is empty.**

How to solve it?

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

I altered registration form by three step registration form for verify customize 6 digit character instead url for email verification.

All works fine. But when I send final request with all params, user created without password.

But if I register from site, all values set well.

I don't understand, whats my problem...

**UPDATED QUESTION 2nd:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Go to "Admin > Configuration > Account settings", and check "Who can register accounts?" option. Try setting it as "Visitors".

Comment: @VishalPatil thanks, I already did it. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

The steps are the following:

1. Please go to: admin/config/people/accounts
2. In the secction "REGISTRATION AND CANCELLATION
   " select "Visitors".
3. Uncheck "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account".
4. Click in the buton "save configuration".

Try again register one user.

I did a test and everything went well.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for reply, I already did it. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Tazim I do not understand. If you register on the page, can you access with username and password? but, if you try to create a user through REST, the values are not saved?

Comment: @Tazim you unmarked "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account".

Comment: @JONATAN thanks for quick reply. Yes, when i try from page, all works fine, but when i try from rest, new user created with all given info, but only password not saved, when i check on database user table, password field is empty.

Comment: yes, i unmarked Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account".

Comment: do you understand now JHONATAN?

Comment: try:                  $http({
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        url: 'yourpage.com/rest/user/register',
        data: {
            "name":"test",
            "pass":"test",
            "mail": "test@test.com",
        }
    }).success(function(userData) { console.log(userData);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });

Comment: try send json :    { "name":"test", "pass":"test", "mail": "test@test.com", "status": 1}

Comment: i updated my question 2nd time with result image. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test and everything works fine.

steps:

1. Please go to: admin/config/people/accounts
2. In the secction "REGISTRATION AND CANCELLATION " select "Visitors".
3. Uncheck "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account".
4. Click in the buton "save configuration".

try the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
    Untitled Document
</title>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#botonesss").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();


 $.ajax({

   data: JSON.stringify({
  "name": "newuser", 
    "mail": "test30@test30.com", 
    "pass": "newuser",
    "status": 1, 
  }),
   url:   'http://localhost/rest/user/register',
   type:  'post',
   beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    },
     success:  function (response) {
      $("#cargaexterna").html(response);
      console.log(response);
     }
  });  //end $.ajax
 }); // end $("#botonesss")
}); // fin $(document).ready(function()
</script>                               
</head>
<body>

 <input id="botonesss"  type="button" value="login">
<div id="cargaexterna"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Modify the URL by your URL and try again.

If it works well, let me know

Comment: I tested your code. I know this will work 100% but my end return same result as empty password.

Comment: sorry to say, maybe i have missed something... trying to find my fault. 

anyway, thank you. Many many thanks... I'll reply comment here if i find my fault...

Comment: For me, your problem is on the line:pass: data.password.   assign a value to the variable: data.password.

Comment: #JHONATAN,
i found my problem. That was register alter function. I missed put password value in there.

I am really sorry for my mistake.

Thanks man. Your coding pattern really inspired me. Coz, i am new on drupal service. I create an app first time with drupal authentication.

Thanks again.

Comment: But one thing, Is service process registration form procedure when i request from service rest api?